# Android: Alert dialoge not showing

Tags: android

I have AsyncTask, after it is doing I show some alert dialoge in onPostExecute. It is working fine.
But if during doInBackground the activity is stoped, after executing AsyncTask the alert dialoge is not showing after activity restart and the activity layout is dim in same way if dialoge is showing.

```
public class CheckPin extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Integer>{
        @Override
        protected Integer doInBackground(String... uri) {
            publishProgress();
            //some code
            return ret;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
            showDialog(CHECKING_PIN);
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            dismissDialog(CHECKING_PIN);
            AlertDialog.Builder mBuilder = new                    AlertDialog.Builder(EnterPin.this); 
                    mBuilder.setMessage("Error") 
                            .setCancelable(false) 
                            .setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.yes), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { 
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                    finish();
                                } 
                            });
                        final AlertDialog mAlert = mBuilder.create(); 
                        mAlert.show();
                        break;


        }
    }
```

Comment: i think you have to remove break from post execute

Comment: still face issues or solved???

Answer (score 0):

```
AlertDialog.Builder mBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(CLASSNAME.this); 
mBuilder.setTitle("Error message")
        .setMessage("You've encountered a problem.") 
        .setCancelable(false) 
        .setPositiveButton("Done", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { 
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                //do something...                               
            } 
})
.create().show();
```

Comment: Do you mean cancelled?  If so just try overriing the onCancelled() method.

Comment: This will work, try again please and mark correct when it's done.

Comment: You cannot show alerts and dialogs from the doInBackground() method. Use the postProgress() and do it in the onProgressUpdate() or wait for the afterExecuted() to show the information from the UI thread.

Comment: alert is not showing from main UI thread if activity is in background.